# Symfony2: Validation of form collection does not work

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Symfony2 validation doesn’t work when Entity Relationships/Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908658/symfony2-validation-doesnt-work-when-entity-relationships-associations)

I have a Form PageFormType, that has just one field named "entries" and no data class.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

  $builder->add('entries', 'collection', array('type' => new EntryFormType() );
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => null  ));
}
```

The setup of the form works great, I see every entry and every field of the EntryFormTypes rendered, but when validationg my PageFormType, it is always valid. Validation of a single EntryFormType would work, but I like to validate all my embedded forms at once. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign validation to your form (see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation). In your case you probably want something like this, using the [Valid-Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Valid;

...

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
        'entities' => new Valid(),
    ));

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The constraints for my Entry Entity are defined as annotation in the Entity class. For sure I am doing something wrong, but just copying your code leads to an error: The constraint Valid cannot be nested inside constraint.Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection. You can only declare the Valid constraint directly on a field or method.   In addition, the main problem is, that there is no relation between my Page Entity and the Entry Entity. But all examples I found assumed this.

Comment: Right, I didn't see that. Well, if repeating the constraints from the entity in the form is not an option, the only other "solution" I can offer is writing a Listener which will validate the data on bind or post_bind.

Comment: +100 That's just fantastic @mahok. Many thanks for this. I couldn't find this in the doc that talks about validation on collections. Would be good to see this in the doc on a section that talks about validation on collections. Great tip.