# Symfony 2 not validating entities in a collection form type?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

My form uses the `uploads` collection type. Each element of the collection is of `UploadType`:

```
class MultiUploadType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('uploads', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new UploadType(), // This should be validated
            'allow_add' => true,
        ));

        $builder->add('Save', 'submit');
    }
}
```

Using javascript I'm able to add new uploads, but validation doesn't work. I've read many questions here ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717882/how-can-i-add-a-violation-to-a-collection), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037203/symfony2-validation-of-form-collection-does-not-work) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908658/symfony2-validation-doesnt-work-when-entity-relationships-associations)) but I can't find a solution yet.

This is how the upload type looks like, while validation is defined using YAML, as the form has a corresponding entity of type `Upload` (file can't be blank):

```
class UploadType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file', 'file');
        $builder->add('description', 'textarea');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'required' => false,
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Upload'
        ));
    }
}
```

Validation code:

```
App\Entity\Upload:
  properties:
    file:
      - NotBlank:
          message: Occorre selezionare un file.
      - File: ~
```

Comment: Pleas show the corresponding validation code.

Comment: @Pazi updated question. Should work out of the box?

Comment: And what about `MultiUpload`?

Comment: @Pazi I'm not using a form model MultiUpload...

Comment: And how do you even bind it in controller?

Comment: @Pazi with a simple array... i suppose it's not possible isn't it? I'll go for a form model + Valid constraint, right?

Answer (score 4):

From comments disscusion:

Yes, basically each form should have a data class. It has not to be a entity, a simple model class is enough. So you can apply validation to it. To validate embed forms the `Valid` assert is required and for collections the same but with the option `traverse: true`.

Comment: Thank you. It works but partially. I've set the `Valid` and `Count` constraints (at least one upload). When no uploads are present an error occurs (correct). If one upload is invalid (i.e. not allowed mime type) and error occurs (correct). BUT if an upload is added without actually select any file, no errors are raised. Any help?